# finding 4th largest element from array using python

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array in which i have element like `a = array.array('i',[3,5,7,2,8,9,10,37,99])`. Now I have to find 4th largest element, If this is a list , then i can find by this way,

```
l = [3,5,7,2,8,9,10,37,99]
m = sorted(l)
m[-4]
```

Comment: So far so good. Time to enlighten us with a question?

Comment: the 4th largest element of what? how would you define what is larger of i and a number?

Comment: `m = sorted(a)`, `m[-4]` will as work. What's the problem?

Comment: Problem is , I want to work this with array in python, it's a list

Comment: @M4rtini Hi... In array we pass i to define that this array is integer type.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `numpy.argsort` that gives you the indices of the min values in order. So:

```
from numpy import argsort
index_to_fourth_largest_element = argsort(a)[-4]
```

But if you use this solution (meaning that you use numpy) and plan to do more with the array you could considering using numpy.array instead of array.array in the first place.